# How to get the IP of aws s3 hosted site

Tags: amazon-s3

I am new to aws, currently I have hosted my site in aws s3 bucket I want the ip address of that site how can I get that ? 
Please find my S3 bucket website url

http://smartmarketsol.com.s3-website-us-west-2.amazonaws.com

Please help me to get the ip of the server.

Awaiting for your response
Bikash

Comment: Why do you want an IP address for your S3 bucket? (Which, by the way, isn't actually possible because it is more than one server.)

Answer (score 10):

`ping smartmarketsol.com.s3-website-us-west-2.amazonaws.com` will give you an IP, however it is not static (fixed) IP as S3's IP can be changed dynamically at any time.

You shouldn't use this IP for DNS purposes.

Answer (score 1):

Can you try with:

```
nslookup smartmarketsol.com.s3-website-us-west-2.amazonaws.com
```